# Traveling between nesting levels in a tibble: how to refer to data stored in upper levels of nesting hierarchy

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr, tibble

I have a *tibble* that contains a *list-column* of data frames. In this minimal example, such tibble has 1 row only:

```r
library(tibble)

df_meta <- 
  tibble(my_base_number = 5,
         my_data = list(mtcars))

df_meta
#> # A tibble: 1 x 2
#>   my_base_number my_data       
#>            <dbl> <list>        
#> 1              5 <df [32 x 11]>
```

I want to modify the table **inside** `my_data` and mutate a new column in there. It's *mtcars* data, and I want to mutate a new column that takes a log of the `mpg` column.

Although I can do this:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df_meta %>%
  mutate(my_data_with_log_col = map(.x = my_data, .f = ~ .x %>% 
                                                         mutate(log_mpg = map(.x = mpg, .f = ~log(.x, base = 5)))
                                    )
         )
#> # A tibble: 1 x 3
#>   my_base_number my_data        my_data_with_log_col
#>            <dbl> <list>         <list>              
#> 1              5 <df [32 x 11]> <df [32 x 12]>
```

What I really want is that the call to `log()` inside inner `map()` will pass the value to the `base` argument from `df_meta$my_base_number` rather than the hard-coded `5` in my example.

And although in this 1-row example this simply works:

```r
df_meta %>%
  mutate(my_data_with_log_col = map(.x = my_data, .f = ~ .x %>% 
                                                         mutate(log_mpg = map(.x = mpg, .f = ~log(.x, base = df_meta$my_base_number)))
                                    )
         )
```

consider just a bit more complicated pipe procedure where it doesn't work anymore:

```r
tibble(my_data = rep(list(mtcars), 3)) %>%
  add_column(base_number = 1:3) %>%
  mutate(my_data_with_log_col = map(.x = my_data, .f = ~ .x %>% 
                                      mutate(log_mpg = map(.x = mpg, .f = ~log(.x, base =  # <- ???
                                                                                 )))
                                    )
  )
```

So what I'm looking for is a procedure that allows me to "travel" up and down in the nesting hierarchy when I refer to different values that are stored in whatever construct in each row of the "meta-table".

Right now, as I go deeper with `map()`, to work on nested tables, I can't refer to data stored *upper*. If you wish, I'm looking for something analoguous to `cd ../../..` when navigating with terminal.

Comment: Use `map2` and pass both the base and the tibble.  If you want to traverse many layers of such nesting, you'll have to pass things through from the outer layers via function parameters.  You probably don't want too many layers (like ../../..) or things will become both slow and incomprehensible

Comment: thanks, @MichaelDewar. Can you show how you'd do it with `map2()`? I tried but couldn't make it work.

Comment: please see my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the method you asked for.  But I actually suggest looking for ways to not be so nested, such as @TarJae's answer.

```
library(tidyverse)

df_meta <- 
    tibble(my_data = rep(list(mtcars), 3),
           my_base_number = 3:5)

add_log <- function(this_data, this_base){
    this_data %>% mutate(log_mpg = log(mpg, this_base))
}

# check that it works properly:
mtcars %>% add_log(5)

# now apply to each row in df_meta
df_meta %>% 
    mutate(my_data_with_log_col = map2(my_data, my_base_number, add_log))
```

You'll notice that I didn't need to use `map` in the inner function.  But if I did, I would use `map_dbl` instead of the `map` that you used, because you actually want a numeric, not a list of vectors of length one.  This also shows that maybe you didn't need the double layered map to begin with.

Also, although an anonymous function is possible, I think it is pretty unreadable for something as complicated as this.  That's why I defined the function outside of the `map2`.

Answer (score 3):

This is not exactly the answer you are asking for.
I want to share it as an option!

You could travel around using the combination of `unnest` and `nest`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df_meta %>% 
  unnest(cols = c(my_data)) %>% 
  mutate(log_mpg = log(mpg, my_base_number)) %>% 
  nest(my_data=mpg:log_mpg)
```

Output after mutate:

```
  my_base_number   mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb log_mpg
            <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>
 1              5  21       6  160    110  3.9   2.62  16.5     0     1     4     4    1.89
 2              5  21       6  160    110  3.9   2.88  17.0     0     1     4     4    1.89
 3              5  22.8     4  108     93  3.85  2.32  18.6     1     1     4     1    1.94
 4              5  21.4     6  258    110  3.08  3.22  19.4     1     0     3     1    1.90
 5              5  18.7     8  360    175  3.15  3.44  17.0     0     0     3     2    1.82
 6              5  18.1     6  225    105  2.76  3.46  20.2     1     0     3     1    1.80
 7              5  14.3     8  360    245  3.21  3.57  15.8     0     0     3     4    1.65
 8              5  24.4     4  147.    62  3.69  3.19  20       1     0     4     2    1.98
 9              5  22.8     4  141.    95  3.92  3.15  22.9     1     0     4     2    1.94
10              5  19.2     6  168.   123  3.92  3.44  18.3     1     0     4     4    1.84
```

Output final after `nest`:

```
  my_base_number my_data           
           <dbl> <list>            
1              5 <tibble [32 × 12]>
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a function inside purrr called `as_mapper`, where you can use  formula syntax to specify the lambda function. You can specify n number of arguments starting with `..1` for `map`, `..1` and `..2` for `map2` and `..1` ..... `..3` .... `..n` for `pmap`. Here is an example:

```r
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(111)
# create some data
df_meta <- tibble(my_base_number = sample(1:5, 5, replace = TRUE), my_data = rerun(5, mtcars))

mutate_log <- as_mapper(~ mutate(..1, log_mpg = log(mpg, ..2)))

df_meta %>%
  mutate(my_data_with_log_col = map2(my_data, my_base_number, mutate_log))
#> # A tibble: 5 × 3
#>   my_base_number my_data        my_data_with_log_col
#>            <int> <list>         <list>              
#> 1              3 <df [32 × 11]> <df [32 × 12]>      
#> 2              4 <df [32 × 11]> <df [32 × 12]>      
#> 3              3 <df [32 × 11]> <df [32 × 12]>      
#> 4              1 <df [32 × 11]> <df [32 × 12]>      
#> 5              3 <df [32 × 11]> <df [32 × 12]>
```

<sup>Created on 2021-12-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Edit: Using `pmap` with `as_mapper`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(111)
# create some data
df_meta <- tibble(
  my_base_number = sample(1:5, 5, replace = TRUE),
  my_col = sample(names(mtcars), 5, replace = TRUE),
  my_data = rerun(5, mtcars)
)

mutate_log <- as_mapper(~ mutate(..1, "log_{..2}" := log(get(..2), ..3)))

#pmap takes two arguments, a list and a function.
data <- df_meta %>%
  mutate(my_data_with_log_col = pmap(list(my_data, my_col, my_base_number), mutate_log))

#check the results
map(data[[4]], head)
#> [[1]]
#>                    mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb  log_drat
#> Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4 1.2388142
#> Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4 1.2388142
#> Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1 1.2270691
#> Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1 1.0239550
#> Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2 1.0444107
#> Valiant           18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1 0.9241028
#> 
#> [[2]]
#>                    mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb log_disp
#> Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4 3.660964
#> Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4 3.660964
#> Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1 3.377444
#> Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1 4.005614
#> Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2 4.245927
#> Valiant           18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1 3.906891
#> 
#> [[3]]
#>                    mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb log_vs
#> Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4   -Inf
#> Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4   -Inf
#> Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1      0
#> Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1      0
#> Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2   -Inf
#> Valiant           18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1      0
#> 
#> [[4]]
#>                    mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb log_gear
#> Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4      Inf
#> Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4      Inf
#> Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1      Inf
#> Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1      Inf
#> Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2      Inf
#> Valiant           18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1      Inf
#> 
#> [[5]]
#>                    mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb  log_mpg
#> Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4 2.771244
#> Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4 2.771244
#> Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1 2.846100
#> Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1 2.788419
#> Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2 2.665657
#> Valiant           18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1 2.635973
```

<sup>Created on 2021-12-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Very interesting! Thanks. Could you please demonstrate how to utilize `as_mapper()` with `pmap()`? For example, if we change `mutate_log()` to `mutate_log <- as_mapper(~ mutate(..1, log_some_col = log(..2, ..3)))` then I'd expect this to work: `df_meta %>% mutate(my_data_with_log_col = pmap(my_data, mpg, my_base_number, mutate_log))`. But it doesn't. Can you please advise?

Comment: @Emman I edited to add the `pmap` case.